# How to tell if an ActiveRecord "where" method created a new row, or obtain an existing one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

How could I tell if the following code created a new record, or returned an existing one? I'm assuming that the `where` method creates a new user here if none exists.

```
# Create User Model Instance
user = User.where(:provider => auth["provider"], :uid => auth["uid"]).first_or_initialize(
  :refresh_token => auth["credentials"]["refresh_token"],
  :access_token => auth["credentials"]["token"],
  :expires => Time.at(auth["credentials"]["expires_at"]).to_datetime,
  :expires_str => auth["credentials"]["expires_at"],
  :name => auth["info"]["name"],
)

# Save User
if user.save
  session[:user_id] = user.id
  notice = "Signed in!"
  logger.debug "URL to redirect to: #{url}"
  redirect_to url, :notice => notice
else
  raise "Failed to login"
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm assuming that the `where` method creates a new user here if none exists.

That is wrong. `where` will never create a new row, it is for *querying* records only.

The way this works is, `first_or_initialize` finds the first matching record, or instants a new **non-saved** record if one wasn't found. In this case, there **is no new record** in the database yet.

Next, you call `user.save!`. *That* creates the record in the case that it didn't exist. `where` had nothing to do with the record's creation.

As for telling whether an ActiveRecord object came from the database or simply exists in memory, you are looking for [`persisted?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/persisted%3F). It returns false is the object has not yet been saved to the database.

```
# Create User Model Instance
user = User.where(:provider => auth["provider"], :uid => auth["uid"]).first_or_initialize(
  :refresh_token => auth["credentials"]["refresh_token"],
  :access_token => auth["credentials"]["token"],
  :expires => Time.at(auth["credentials"]["expires_at"]).to_datetime,
  :expires_str => auth["credentials"]["expires_at"],
  :name => auth["info"]["name"],
)

# At this point, if user.persisted? is true, the user was found in the database.
# The below call to `save` will update the record.
# OR
# If false, the user doesn't exist in the database yet.
# The below call to save will insert the record

# Save User
if user.save
  session[:user_id] = user.id
  notice = "Signed in!"
  logger.debug "URL to redirect to: #{url}"
  redirect_to url, :notice => notice
else
  raise "Failed to login"
end
```